# App for Office for Desktop and 3rd party authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, office365

I am initiating an App for Office project and I am trying to find out something critical. 
Can I use my ASP.NET MVC built-in OAuth authentication to pair it with a Live account so my app logs-in the user into MS Office for Desktop apps. 
This is needed so I can access OneDrive and use the share file editing there.

The architecture so far is:

- Files stored in a single OneDrive or SharePoint server (TBD)
- Desktop Office apps (Word and Excel) where the users work.
- App for Office, installed in their Word and Excel. Users can authenticate on the back-end ASP.NET MVC server, using any 3rd party email address and a password.

I have used OAuth in ASP.NET MVC projects but not in integration with Office in an App for Office.
So, my question is if this idea is possible and HOW, or I have to give everyone an Office 365 account so they can connect via the integrate Office for desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone's benefit, I will explain what we have done.

We are using Azure Active Directory and manage all users there. We connected SharePoint site to it and it has a OneDrive behind. Now our App for Office connects to that using SharePointContext from [here](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/RestSharpSample/blob/master/RESTishWeb/SharePointContext.cs) and it magically works.

Answer (score 1):

As we in our small company like to benefit from the OneDrive  functionality, and also want to have selected shared and group folders offline available, we found a more or less perfect workaround.
We use the Goodsync software to synchronize. For this you create a sync job within  Goodsync  for  the folders you want to have offline- available. Such a sync definition / call it folder pair / has a reference to the local folder, and on the other side a reference to the OneDrive  folder.  The reference to the OneDrive  folder you describe like this:  „sds://d.docs.live.net//“.
The OneDrive  CID you can see for any shared OneDrive  folder in OneDrive  web  whithin its web address (example:  https://OneDrive.live.com/?cid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) . Similarly it works for OneDrive  group folders. 
Our experience is very good with this workaround, only to be aware to have all rights for the shared One Drive folder, then Goodsync  can even create or delete folders within shared OneDrives.
Good luck!   Wolfgang from Salzburg